# Respond Unauthorized from ModelBinder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have a WebApi ModelBinder that's used to convert from a string in a url to an object representing what segment of a website a client is requesting.  Clients only have access to certain website segments.

Can I handle authorization from the ModelBinder?  Right now I'm doing this which does return a 401; however, the Api controller code still gets executed.

```
class SegmentModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
            return false;

        if (/*doesn't have access*/)
            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        else
            bindingContext.Model = /*set object*/;

        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I respond with a 401, and also end the execution of the request at that point?

Answer (score 1):

Could you utilize `actionContext.ModelState.IsValid` in both the ModelBinder and the action?

I guess a higher level question, are you able to just decorate the action with the 
`[Authorize]` attribute since you want to end execution upon failed authorization.

Comment: Thanks; I posted my changes based on this answer.  I don't believe I'm using the modelstate anywhere so hopefully this shouldn't cause issues elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

From vandsh's response, I made the following changes:

ModelBinder:

```
    if (/*doesn't have access*/)
        actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Segment", String.Format("Unauthorized Segment: {0}", segment));
    else
        bindingContext.Model = /*set object*/;
```

Added a new filter:

```
public class ValidModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
    }
}
```

And added that filter in global.asax.cs:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new Api.Filters.ValidModelAttribute());
```